# Setup local dns server that merges Google DNS and OpenNIC

Tags: bind

I would like to setup bind9 on my local computer, such that common dns queries like com, de, net are forwarded to Google DNS and the other custom made ones from OpenNic like bbs, dyn, free are forwarded to a OpenNIC-DNS server.

The dns-server shouldn't do caching or download all zone files from the OpenNIC-DNS-Servers.

Can you help me?

**Here is my not working configuration:**

```
//named.conf:
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

.

```
//named.conf.default-zones
zone "localhost" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.local";
};

zone "127.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.127";
};

zone "0.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.0";
};

zone "255.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.255";
};
```

.

```
// named.conf.local:
// replace all '...' with the following:
//      type forward;
//      forwarders {78.138.98.82; 78.138.97.33;};
//      forward only;
zone "dns.opennic.glue" in { ... };
zone "bbs" in { ... };
zone "dyn" in { ... };
zone "free" in { ... };
zone "fur" in { ... };
zone "geek" in { ... };
zone "gopher" in { ... };
zone "indy" in { ... };
zone "ing" in { ... };
zone "micro" in { ... };
zone "neo" in { ... };
zone "null" in { ... };
zone "opennic.glue" in { ... };
zone "oss" in { ... };
zone "oz" in { ... };
zone "parody" in { ... };
zone "pirate" in { ... };
```

.

```
// named.conf.options
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; };
    forward only;
    dnssec-validation auto;
    auth-nxdomain no;
};
```

Here the output of traceroute for google.com and grep.geek:

```
# tracerout google.com
traceroute to google.com (173.194.116.192), 64 hops max
 1   192.168.178.1 (192.168.178.1) 1.436ms 1.195ms 1.195ms 
 2   80.69.104.84 (80.69.104.84) 10.818ms 9.268ms 16.093ms 
 3   *  *  * 
 4   72.14.213.197 (72.14.213.197) 41.229ms 36.026ms 36.034ms 
 5   72.14.238.46 (72.14.238.46) 11.824ms 9.628ms 9.822ms 
 6   66.249.94.143 (66.249.94.143) 12.487ms 17.118ms 19.893ms 
 7   173.194.116.192 (173.194.116.192) 10.171ms 9.559ms 9.874ms
```

.

```
traceroute grep.geek
traceroute to hit-nxdomain.opendns.com (67.215.65.132), 64 hops max
 1   192.168.178.1 (192.168.178.1) 2.605ms 2.242ms 1.218ms 
 2   80.69.104.84 (80.69.104.84) 9.502ms 11.883ms 13.299ms 
 3   80.69.105.209 (80.69.105.209) 9.645ms 9.366ms  * 
 4   80.69.107.214 (80.69.107.214) 13.783ms 11.845ms 12.632ms 
 5   80.69.107.21 (80.69.107.21) 15.165ms 17.931ms 23.894ms 
 6   80.69.107.209 (80.69.107.209) 16.423ms 21.342ms 18.070ms 
 7   80.69.107.9 (80.69.107.9) 21.847ms 19.817ms 19.860ms 
 8   84.116.197.253 (84.116.197.253) 32.887ms 40.201ms 36.557ms 
 9   84.116.133.230 (84.116.133.230) 36.050ms 31.760ms 31.942ms 
10   195.66.225.70 (195.66.225.70) 31.176ms 30.835ms 30.011ms 
11   67.215.65.132 (67.215.65.132) 34.920ms 34.592ms 42.566ms
```

Comment: Look into "Conditional Forwarding": [Conditional DNS forwarding with named on Linux](http://serverfault.com/questions/99101/conditional-dns-forwarding-with-named-on-linux)

Comment: I already tried it like this, but I only get an error page when I try to access a server with an openNic domain.

(error page: http://www.website-unavailable.com/main?wc=EWJtHRd6AAVAABRuAAo%3D&url=grep.geek&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opennicproject.org%2F&w=1360&h=601&ifc=0)

Comment: Perhaps post the results of a `tracert` to each of the two types of extensions (say a .com and a .bbs) so we can see how it's being routed. Also, "website-unavailable.com" is an OpenDNS thing as far as I know, which is NOT OpenNIC. :)  What DNS servers are you trying to forward to for each type's lookups?

Comment: For google DNS I use 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 and for OpenNIC DNS 78.138.98.82 and 78.138.97.33

Comment: I just tried to reach opennic.glue and that does work with my dns server. In my config file it also appears as a zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the cause, why my dns server wasn't working properly.

In named.conf.options dnssec-validation has to be set to no, otherwise the dns servers of opennic are ignored:

```
// named.conf.options
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; };
    forward only;
    dnssec-validation no;
    auth-nxdomain no;
};
```

Solution was found at: https://serverfault.com/questions/413600/bind-9-7-3-not-forwarding-to-isp-dns-server-only-local-resolving-successful